# Many to Many relationship Schema

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the following tables:

### Table INFO

```
_id: unique id
record_id: varchar
info: varchar
```

### Table emails

```
_id: unique_id
record_id: references (INFO.record_id)
email: varchar
```

In this scenario, emails can relate to different INFO rows. What would be the better way to create such a table with the proper relationship? Can I create a foreign key on emails pointing to a nonunique id (`record_id`) on `INFO`?

And then how can I query such as I have one row for each INFO row that includes all the emails from the emails table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned already - introduce JOIN table, which would look like below. It's better to keep foreign key reference to primary key in referenced table.

**InfoEmails**

```
info_id: references (INFO._id)
email_id: references (EMAIL._id)
```

The primary key in table `InfoEmails` can be concatenated foreign keys - for example `info_id + email_id`. This would ensure uniqueness and you would not need to introduce probably not needed `Id` column. If you decide so introduce also index on `email_id + info_id` for performance look-ups reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `record_id` column in `emails` that references the `INFO` table, you have a **one-to-many** relationship. Adding a `UNIQUE` constraint makes it a **one-to-one** (or none) relationship. If you want a **many-to-many** relationship between two tables, you must describe the relationship with a *third table*. The additional table will have columns for the primary keys for both of the tables you want to relate to each other.

To query the relationship, you `JOIN` between one table and the new table, and then again from the new table to the other table. If you're new to SQL: yes, you can have *many* `JOIN`s in the same query. You can even join the same table more than once.

Comment: What happens if I keep the reference but that column is not unique? Does the join on that `record_id` field work as expected or can create issues?

Comment: A `Unique` constraint would actually be **one-to-one** (or none). No constraint (the default) is still one-to-many, because each email can only relate to one INFO. Many-to-many means each INFO can relate to many emails, and **also** each email can relate to many INFOs.